# Conduction problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-conductivity

A hot reservoir with a temperature of $782 K$ is $0.56 m$ away from a cold reservoir with a temperature of $331 K$. The two reservoirs are insulated from each other except for a rod of brass ($k = 109 \frac{W}{m*K}$) that has a cross-sectional area of $0.056 m^2$. The entire system is allowed to reach a steady-state condition.

Question: Assume that you need to transfer $6336540 J$ of energy in ten minutes between the two reservoirs. To enhance the rate of energy transfer, a steel rod ($k = 43 \frac{W}{m*K}$) of the same length is added between the two reservoirs. What should the cross-sectional area of the steel rod be in order to achieve the proper rate of energy transfer?

I know the equation is $\frac{dQ}{dt} = -kA \frac{dT}{dx}$ but I still cannot get the right answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in the case of your question, the brass rod and the steel rod are connected in parallel combination in between the hot reservoir and the cold reservoir. So the thermal resistance will be given by:
$$\frac{1}{R_p} = \frac{(k_1A_1+k_2A_2)}{l}$$
And we know that, $$\frac{Q}{t} = \frac{dT}{R_p} = \frac{(k_1A_1+k_2A_2)\cdot dT}{l}$$. You have been given the values of $Q$, $t$, $k_1$, $k_2$, $A_1$, and $dT$
Therefore you can easily calculate the value of $A_2$ which is your required answer. When I did this question, I found the answer to be $0.163$ $m^2$.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I did (k1+k2)(A1+A2). Thank you.